# Form in a colorbox popup won't submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, colorbox

I've got a form which pop-ups on click to edit the selected item.

When I hit submit it just reloads the page and nothing else happens.

I've tried so many approaches but no luck so far.

So this is my html:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <div class="cust_row_10"><a href="item_info.php?id=3" title="Click to view the item" class="itemPopup">item 3</a></div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="cust_row_10"><a href="item_info.php?id=4" title="Click to view the item" class="itemPopup">item 4</a></div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

and JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.itemPopup').colorbox({ transition:'none', width:'90%', height:'90%'});
});
```

Comment: You'll need to attach a click event and return false so that the default won't execute.

Comment: @Daan This should/could be an answer.

Comment: Can you paste your colorbox code?

Comment: My colorbox code is the JS provided in my question, but anyway:  $('.itemPopup').colorbox({ transition:'none', width:'90%', height:'90%'}); Thanks!